# SSH over VPN (openconnect) in one line

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openconnect

I have succeeded the following commands:

```
sudo openconnect hoge.com
ssh -p <PORT> user@IP
```

But I cannot execute these commands with one line.

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='echo "PASS" | sudo openconnect hope.com --user=<hoge.com's username> --passwd-on-stdin' user@IP -p <PORT>
```

However, I can run these command.

```
echo "PASS" | sudo openconnect hope.com --user=<hoge.com's username> --passwd-on-stdin
ssh -p <PORT> user@IP
```

How can I execute ssh commands with openconnect on one line?
Or How can I ssh with openconnect via `/.ssh/config`?